# What is the truth value for the statement ∀∃ ( −  = 0) →  >  Given the domain of discourse is Real numbers?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

What is the truth value for the statement
∀∃ ( −  = 0) →  >  Given the domain of discourse is
Real numbers?

Comment: I assume you mean to ask about the truth value of $$\forall x\exists y\Big((x-y=0)\to x>y\Big)$$  In what you've written the appearance of $x, y$ in $x>y$ are free variables, non-quantified.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the missing brackets, that's equivalent to $\forall x\exists y(x = y \to x > y)$.

Now ask yourself what happens if the antecedent of the conditional is false ...